# ProcessInputStream.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

The app has 1000s of users, but we've had a few reports of the following crash which is puzzling:

```
  Fatal Exception java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
  java.lang.ProcessManager$ProcessInputStream.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
```

This looks like it happened in the FinalizerWatchdogDaemon and has so far only been seen on some Android 4.2 and 4.3 devices.

According to the crash logs, the main thread at the time was generating a couple of template bitmaps (it only does this if they don't already exist, which on first time after an install, they wouldn't).

```
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Bitmap.java)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:912)
```

Specifically, we were calling Bitmap.compress to save a Bitmap as a PNG to a BufferedOutputStream (which was a file).

I've not been able to find any other information as to what might cause this.  Has anyone seen these issues before or know how to resolve it?

Comment: Do you release every bitmap after each call ?

Comment: Hi @Manitoba, yes, we create a BufferedOutputStream, call Bitmap.compress(..), close the stream, then call recycle() on the Bitmap.  It just seems to get stuck on the Bitmap.compress(..) call sometimes.

The Bitmaps are quite large (720x1280) but all it has to do is encode to PNG and save to sdcard.